# Why are boundary points preserved by smooth maps?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, surfaces, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm reading some lecture notes on representation of  surfaces groups.

Author defines a surface with boundary to be:

> A surface with boundary is a metrisable space S together
> with a smooth atlas of charts with boundary.

To define the boundary of the "surface with boundary" object, we use the auxiliary lemma:

> Let S be a surface with boundary and let $(U_1, \phi_1)$ $(U_2, \phi_2)$ be charts with boundary in an atlas of S.
>
> Suppose $x \in \partial U_1 \cap U_2$ . in other words x is a boundary point of $U_1$ .
> Then $x \in \partial U_2$ .

The proof for this lemma is omitted, and I'm having trouble coming up with it myself.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: For a boundary point in a coordinate neighbourhoood, there is a tangent vector pointing “out” of the chart i.e. Any small translation in that direction would Force you to leave the chart  , this is not the case for interior points. To see that transition morphisms between boundary neighbourhoods map preserve this property it is enough to show that tangent vectors pointing out of the coordinate nbhd get mapped to tangent vectors pointing out of the image nbhd.

Comment: Thanks @LBE, that was helpful

Comment: If you consider boundary charts, transition functions are maps between non-open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$. Which defnition od smoothness do you use in that case?

Comment: Given a function $f:V_1 \rightarrow V_2$, where: $V_1 , V_2 \subset H^{+}$, we say that f is smooth if there exist an open set $\tilde{V_1} \subset R^2$ such that: $\tilde{V_1} \subset R^2$ and: $\tilde{V_1} \cap {H}^{+}$ and a smooth function $\tilde{f}:\tilde{V_1} \rightarrow R^2$ such that $f= \tilde{f} $ on  $V_1$

Comment: We use this one to define smoothness of function from the upper-half of the plane, marked $H^{+}$ above, to itself. Does that answer your question @PaulFrost?

Comment: @NG_ Yes, it is clear now. But you should add this information to your question.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks. Will edit soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{H}^n=\{(x^1,\cdots,x^n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:x^1\ge 0\}$ denote the upper half space and $\partial\mathbb{H}^n=\{(0,x^2,\cdots,x^n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$ denote its boundary. Note that open subsets of $\mathbb{H}^n$ will not necessarily be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The crux of the argument can be stated this way:

> **Theorem**: Given any diffeomorphism $\varphi:U\to V$ where $U,V\subseteq\mathbb{H}^n$ are open subsets, $x\in U$ is a boundary point iff $\varphi(x)\in V$ is a boundary point, i.e. $\varphi(\partial\mathbb{H}^n\cap U)=\partial\mathbb{H}^n\cap V$.

There are a number of ways of proving this; here's one: we can say that a point $x\in\mathbb{H}^n$ *has an inextendible curve* if there is a smooth curve $\gamma:[0,a)\to\mathbb{H}^n$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$ and the domain of $\gamma$ cannot be extended to an open interval. Inextendible curves have a few important properties:

- Inextendible curves are a local property, in that the condition would be equivalent if we choose any open subset $U\subset\mathbb{H}^n$ containing $x$ and require the curve and its extension to map into $U$.
- $x\in\mathbb{H}^n$ has an inextendible curve iff $x\in\partial\mathbb{H}^n$.
- If $\varphi:U\to V$ is a diffeomorphism with $U,V\subseteq\mathbb{H}^n$ open subsets, then $x$ has an inextendible curve iff $\varphi(x)$ does.

These can be proven using the definitions of continuity and smoothness on subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In fact, boundary points are a topological invariant, in that we can modify the theorem to only require that $\varphi$ be a homeomorphism. This case can be proven using relative homology, or fundamental groups in the $n=2$ case.

Comment: Thank you @Kajelad. The last paragraph you wrote sparked my interest; Any chance you can point me to a reference to proving topological invariance using the fundamental group where n=2?

Comment: @NG_ This appears as an exercise in Ch. 8 of Lee's *Introduction to Topological manifolds*, also the subject of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3414093/invariance-of-the-boundary-for-2-dimensional-manifold). The basic argument is that every boundary $x$ has a basis of neighborhoods $U_i$ such that $U_i\setminus\{x\}$ is simply connected, and no such neighborhoods exist for interior points.